# Trying to animate burger menu using javascript, however it's not working and can't find any errors

Tags: javascript

I've written a couple lines of Javascript to animate the burger menu on my website however it has stopped working. I'm not sure why this is as it was previously working. I've changed the names of some folders, however I can't find any typos.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/ofz7hfa.css">
        <link href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src ="Images/Logo.png" alt=" logo" class ="logo">
            </div>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="index.html"> HOME </a></li>
                    <li><a href="About Me/index.html"> ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Projects/index.html">PROJECTS </a></li>
                    <li><a href="Misc/index.html"> BLOG</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
        </nav>
            <script> src='javascript/personal.js'</script>
        </body>
</html>


const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click',() => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });
}
navSlide();
```

Comment: Looks fine, are you sure you have right selector in css file? Im talking about 'nav-active'

Comment: @KacperWitas yeah I did double check that. Still not working...